# Either type validation in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have two controls one dropdown (cmbCategories) and second one input textbox (txtCategory).

Now, I want to add validation. If Category is not selected from cmbCategories dropdown, it will look for txtCategory textbox. **If both are not present then it should be given an error** just say 'Either you have to select Category from dropdown list or enter into Category textbox'.

I have used following type validation rules but it gives unexpected results.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cmbCategories','Category','required|is_natural|xss_clean');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtCategory','Category','required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
```

*How I achieve the functionality that I am looking for?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI's validation methods can only be called on a single input so I don't think that you will be able to use them alone for what you are trying to do. I would just check the post vars that are submitted and make sure that they both aren't empty.

```
if ($this->input->post('cmbCategories') == 0 && $this->input->post('txtCategory') == '')
{
    // set error message and stop processing
}
```